# I reached a generous job offer, but it doesn’t include a personal use vehicle. How do I approach them about this?

Tags: negotiation

Just as a background, I received a generous permanent full-time employment offer of $8k/year extra of what I have asked during my screening.

The Employment Agreement specifies:

> You will be provided a vehicle to use for work. It may be used for
>   personal travel in line with the [Company X] vehicle procedure.
>
> Use of the vehicle will be limited to: Travel between home and work
>   with any diversion for private purposes adding no more than 2km to the
>   ordinary length of that trip.
>   Blockquote

How do I go on approaching the employer for a full “reasonable” personal use of a vehicle despite getting a generous offer?

This is an intermediate technical position that requires 2 years experience. Although I am happy to accept this offer considering the very healthy company culture, scope of works and future works but sparking a negotiation conversation is very natural.

Should I approach the Hiring Manager via a quick phone call, or email her directly, or just accept the offer “as is”?

Cheers.

Comment: What is a full "reasonable" use? You could try and have a monthly personal mileage allowance included - then you have to decide how much you want. It's best, though, to have a figure in mind, rather than (appear) to be asking for unlimited personal mileage

Comment: What is the country? Sometimes there can be legal limits that if exceed would make things more expensive.

Comment: Is this a dealbreaker for you? Are you going to turn down the offer if you don't get this?

Comment: Too much personal use can get you to pay the tax on it , depends on country etc

Comment: On further thought, if they stick to the commute-plus-2km I'd maybe ask them to drop the car and add more salary, since you're going to need to buy, insure, maintain, and fuel a car for personal use anyway.

Comment: Is using the vehicle within the current confines of the agreement a hardship for you? I'm having a hard time believing that you'd turn down the job because of this.

Comment: @joeqwerty unless it's some sort of traveling sales/consulting engineer/etc job and the reason they're providing a car is so you're not putting an extra 15-45k/year on yours.  Other than that, outside of some sort of executive perk, I can't imagine a car being part of a standard offer.  Outside of a road job, even if I was allowed to use it for all my  personal driving I'd rather have what they paid for the car added to my salary, because having to buy a car on no notice if I was fired would really suck; so I'd be keeping my personal vehicle anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would call the hiring manager and ask for clarification on using the vehicle for personal use....just to ensure you understand what their policy is, how many miles you can drive over the ordinary trip, etc. You may just not be understanding the policy, so get full clarification and be sure you understand it.

Once you go through that, I'd just say...

> Thank you so much for the explanation, I really appreciate it. I'm used to being able to use my business car for personal use, so this is a bit new for me. Is there a way that this can be negotiated as well or not?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I approach the Hiring Manager via a quick phone call

It can't hurt to clarify if they are any options available to change the terms and conditions. There probably aren't but there is no harm in finding out for sure.